# TimePeriodLibrary Intersect two time periods

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have been fighting against the TimePeriodLibrary for the past few hours already. I simply want to compare two time periods in order to determine their intersection...

According to [codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET) it seems that TimePeriodLibrary offers this capability.

In my case I use the very simple code below:

```
public ICollection<TimeRange> Extract(TimeRange range, TimeSpan? maxDuration = null)
{
    (...)
    var res = _source.IntersectionPeriods(range);
    (...)
}
```

With source being an instance of type `TimePeriodCollection`

When :

- _source is a period starting from 6/3/2018 12:00:00 PM to 6/3/2021 1:00:00 PM
- range is a period starting from 30/3/2018 12:00:00 AM to 31/3/2018 12:00:00 AM
- **Outcome**: the intersection contains everything from _source
- **Expected**: period starting from 30/3/2018 12:00:00 AM to 31/3/2018 12:00:00

What am I missing?

Comment: You've specified three cases in the description, but then provided code which looks different - and you haven't said which case is failing. (Your final piece of description doesn't seem to match any of the three test cases you described.) Could you provide a [mcve] showing just what's failing? At the moment the question is very unclear because of all the different test cases being talked about.

Comment: i have simplified the question

Comment: If `range` is completely outside of `_source`, why are you expecting it to return any period at all; let alone one that isn't in `_source`? UNLESS the code is JUST looking at the time and not the date; in which case it will return the `_source` you describe; because the time range is inside the time range provided by `range`

Comment: Actually in my example, range is fully included within _source (this period covers 3 years)

Comment: You haven't provided a [mcve] - you've just provided a method declaration with a single line of code in. Please help us to help you - write an example which we can copy, paste, compile and run, which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Seb ah, in that case it's working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question says:

- _source is a period starting from 6/3/2018 12:00:00 PM to 6/3/2021 1:00:00 PM
- range is a period starting from 30/3/2018 12:00:00 AM to
  31/3/2018 12:00:00 AM
- Outcome: the intersection contains everything
  from _source
- Expected: period starting from 30/3/2018 12:00:00 AM to
  31/3/2018 12:00:00 AM

What `IntersectionPeriods` does is returns all of the periods in `_source` that intersect with the provided `range`. Your range `from 30/3/2018 12:00:00 AM to
   31/3/2018 12:00:00 AM` intersects with `from 6/3/2018 12:00:00 PM to 6/3/2021 1:00:00 PM`, and so the _source range is returned. Therefore, the code is working as it should.

It looks like you're trying to find if the `range` intersects `_source` somehow, rather than which items in `_source` intersects `range`?

Comment: Huuuuum I see what you mean. That makes sense. I though this would give me the intersection between two timeperiodcollection!